# What type of special information should the Project Management FAQ contain?

Tags: discussion, beta

Each site has it's own unique FAQ.  Some of the information is common to all Stack Exchange sites, but other information in the FAQ is very specific to the individual site itself.

For Project Management, what type of information should be included in the FAQ?

Comment: Is it possible  to convert this to a community wiki question?  Does anyone here have permissions to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Robert Cartaino in [this question](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24/is-this-site-about-objective-questions-or-subjective-questions-can-the-site-sur), I think we should put "How the subjective question should be asked", based on this post: [Good subjective, Bad subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).

Because there maybe lots of subjective questions, I think this is necessary to raise the quality of those questions.

Comment: Agreed!  Good, quality questions are important, and having the guidelines clearly spelled out will be helpful.  I wonder if they can also put that in the section above the question textbox to make it stand out.  Not everyone sees the FAQ right away.